# Incorrect "You can only comment every 5 seconds" message

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, rate-limiting

- I posted a couple of comments
- I edited them a couple of times
- I tried to edit one of them again (much more than 5 seconds had passed)

=> I got the error "You can only comment every 5 seconds".

So I patiently waited about 10 seconds and tried again.
=> same error

So I patiently waited more than 15 seconds and tried again
=> same error

Eventually I gave up.
Then after a few minutes, I went back to edit my comment, and the "edit" link has even disappeared: I can't edit it any more at all.

By the way I was editing the comments in order to correct/improve formatting

Comment: Did you try simply refreshing the page? Did you just post a new, clarifying comment? Do you have a link to the comment in question?

Comment: I'm not sure whether i tried refreshing the page. No I didn't post a clarifying comment, I didn't deem it worth it (I was just trying to correct the formatting). The link to the comment is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501704/does-sql-standard-allows-whitespace-between-function-names-and-parenthesis/2501808#comment10831956_2501808

And by the way I was wrong about the formatting help, i was just desperately trying to put some line breaks in it :P

Comment: Copy/paste the content to a new comment, delete the old comment, and fix the formatting in the new one.  You'll lose your place in line, but that's the way it works.

Comment: Are you still noticing this issue?

Comment: Gonna try.

Fourth edit.... seems it works now

Comment: @kiamlaluno seems it works fine now. Now if 5 minutes have passed from the posting of the comment, I get the error "Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes" (expected), so I guess the problem was that the wrong error message was being shown, and it seems to be fixed.

Comment: Seems to be happening again in Chrome on Stack Overflow.